# how to break up a big request and use maps for constant

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql, hortonworks-data-platform

I'm developing data mart from query from several big tables that has been running for more than 20 minutes. To make my code more readable and avoid magic number and word I use hivevar map, instead constant:

```
select b.id1 as id1,
       -- near 30 fields with nested if, match case etc, like
       if( d7.recordid = '01'
               or d7.recordid = '02'
               or -- ... 10 expressions
           'expression1',
           'expression2'
           ) as trans_type,
       b.id2 as id2
```

This query (without hive maps) executes during 13 min.

Please tell me how to improve this query and avoid magic number inside to make it faster.

```
set hivevar:transaction_class_code=map('INTERNAL',     '01',
                                       'INTERNATIONAL',  '02',
                                       -- 10 elements
                                       );


select b.id1 as id1,
       -- near 30 fields with nested if, match case etc, like
       if( d7.recordid = ${transaction_class_code}['INTERNAL']
               or d7.recordid = ${transaction_class_code}['INTERNATIONAL']
               or -- ... 10 expressions
           'expression1',
           'expression2'
           ) as trans_type,
       b.id2 as id2
from banks b -- ~10_000_000_000 rows, ~100 columns
join trans t -- 10_000_000 rows
     on b.id1 = t.id1
    and b.id2 = t.id2
left join customer c -- 3_000_000_000 rows
     on b.customer_id = c.transaction_customer_id
    and b.id1 = c.bank_id
left join transactions_pa  tp -- 500_000_000 rows
     on b.id1 = tp.bank_id
    and b.id2 = tp.transaction_id
left join transaction_dict   td -- 100_000_000
     on b.id1 = td.bank_id
    and b.id2 = td.transaction_id
left join dict1 d1 --5_152
     on b.instance = d1.instance
    and b.transaction_dict1_id = d1.recid
-- 4 dictionaries with 5 - 10 columns and 500 - 3000 rows
left join dictionary6 d7 -- 2116
     on b.instance = d6.instance
    and b.transaction_dict6_id = d6.recid;
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide EXPLAIN command output also. Is it possible? Or maybe you have a problem with obfuscating it?

Comment: Or check it yourself  table sizes in bytes and are all small tables joins are being done in MapJoin operator